# Reset build settings to default in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

How do I reset build settings to default in Xcode?

Answer (score 85):

To reset a single project setting so that it's no longer bold, select the option in the project settings and hit the delete key.

Comment: What does it mean when this does not work? Its not important cause I have set the value to what is in the 'IOS Default' column, but being obsessive-compulsive I would love to get them back to non-bold :)

Comment: Hah, I knew it had to be something deceptively simple like this.

Comment: If 'delete' does nothing - select appropriate item in project/target selector in top left corner of settings view.

Comment: If you really want complete control, you can edit the `project.pbxproj` file directly to remove the offending setting, but you risk making the project unusable.

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode reset build settings to default**

When a target's setting is changed Xcode **bold** it. Also you can find all changed settings in `Customized` tab. Moreover you can check who exactly influences on the value using `Levels` tab.

[image]

To **reset**(unbold) a value just **select** and press <kbd>delete</kbd> key

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially with multi-line items, hitting delete or cmd-delete does not work. For those items I just resort to setting the first line to `$(inherited)`. This means the item is still bold, but it will otherwise have the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Hitting Delete didn't work for me, but that's because I was looking at the settings from the point of view of the target, when the setting was set for the project. Switching to the project view worked -- hitting Delete removed my setting and reverted back to the default (non-bold) value.